# Non numeric to binary operator error in R console

Tags: r

I am trying to add the % symbol i front of my perc.of.adult function in a bar diagram but the non numeric to binary code keeps appearing for some reason. How do I accomplish this without this error?

```r
perc.of.adults<- c(1.8,36.7,35.3,26.2)
labels1 = paste0(" (", perc.of.adults, "%)")
perc.of.adults=labels1

barplot(
  perc.of.adults, names.arg=c("Underweight", "Healthy weight" , "Overweight" , "Obese"),
  xlab="Weight category", ylab="Percentage" ,
  main="Bar Graph of Weight Category Against Percent of Adults")
```

Comment: How can you make a barplot out of strings? `barplot(" (1.8%)")` is not a normal thing.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `numeric` form of `perc.of.adults` and add the labels second.

```r
perc.of.adults <- c(1.8, 36.7, 35.3, 26.2)
labels1 <- paste0(" (", perc.of.adults, "%)")
bp <- barplot(
  perc.of.adults, names.arg=c("Underweight", "Healthy weight" , "Overweight" , "Obese"),
  xlab="Weight category", ylab="Percentage" ,
  main="Bar Graph of Weight Category Against Percent of Adults")
bp
#      [,1]
# [1,]  0.7
# [2,]  1.9
# [3,]  3.1
# [4,]  4.3
text(bp[,1], perc.of.adults + ifelse(perc.of.adults < 5, 4, -4), labels1)
```

[image: barplot with labels]

(It's worth noting that `barplot` returns a matrix with the centers of the x positions of the bars. What's really noteworthy is that with four bars, they are not centered on `1:4`, but a little spread out. Whatever the history or rationale for this, it's easy to capture and use.)